# Using describe() twice during Karma Jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

So I'm running through the AngularJS tutorial, I'm on Chapter 5, and I came across this Karma test. It looks like this:

```
'use strict';

/* jasmine specs for controllers go here */
describe('PhoneCat controllers', function() {

  describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){
    var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      $httpBackend.expectGET('phones/phones.json').
          respond([{name: 'Nexus S'}, {name: 'Motorola DROID'}]);

      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl3', {$scope: scope});
    }));


    it('should create "phones" model with 2 phones fetched from xhr', function() {
      expect(scope.phonez).toBeUndefined();
      $httpBackend.flush();

      expect(scope.phonez).toEqual([{name: 'Nexus S'},
                                   {name: 'Motorola DROID'}]);
    });


    it('should set the default value of orderProp model', function() {
      expect(scope.orderProp).toBe('age');
    });
  });
});
```

The code it is testing looks like this:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var phonecatApp1 = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp1.controller('PhoneListCtrl3', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.phonez = data;
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.err = "Cannot make connection to data. Reason: " + status + data;
        console.log("Error status : " + status);
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}]);
```

My question is, why do they call describe twice? I removed the inital describe from the test, namely `describe('PhoneCat controllers', function()` and the test passed without any problems.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

describe methods adds a test suite, it is just for separation of the test cases -

see below example -

```html
describe('PhoneCat controllers', function() {

  describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){
    //Phone list controller tests goes here
  }

  describe('PhoneDetailsCtrl', function(){
    //Phone details controller tests goes here
  }
}
```

it adds nothing but the separation in test cases. [Click here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html) for more information on describe method

Comment: so the describe method can have an original name? It doesn't have to correspond to a defined controller?

Comment: @emporio - its the random text. Its just the meaningful description of the test suite!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your expertise!